# C# - Have an index array full of strings that I want to print as strings instead of chars

Tags: c#, arrays, string, char, string-interpolation

Can someone help me print out a **string** instead of a char via *string interpolation* when your strings are **indexed in an array?** As seen the printed in the *if statement* - **{text[3]}** etc.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string textDoc = "The first world war occurred in the early 20th century, many countries around the world were originally agnostic to the early battles. An obvious reason why is because there are many countries in the world that do not have relations to nation states that were fighting in the early battles.";

    string[] textSplit = textDoc.Split(" ");
    
    foreach (string text in textSplit) {
        if(text.StartsWith("a")) {
            Console.WriteLine($"Roses {text[2]} red, scarlets {text[2]} blue, this poem doesn't have {text[3]} ending, so embrace the unknown because it is {text[1]}.");
            break;
        }
    }
```

{text[3]} prints out the char - **"a"**, instead of a string - **"are"**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //options/configuration values which may work better as parameters
        string source = "The first world war occurred in the early 20th century, many countries around the world were originally agnostic to the early battles. An obvious reason why is because there are many countries in the world that do not have relations to nation states that were fighting in the early battles.";
        string template = "Roses {0} red, scarlets {1} blue, this poem doesn't have {2} ending, so embrace the unknown because it is {3}.";
        //When true both "around" and "An" will match "a". When false only "around" will
        bool ignoreCase = true;
        int numberOfBlanks = 4;
        //word to use in blanks if not enough matching words are found. use an empty string "" if you don't want anything filled
        string defaultWord = "banana";
        string matchingLetter = "a";
        
        string[] madgabWords = new string[numberOfBlanks];
        Array.Fill(madgabWords, defaultWord);
        
        
        string[] textSplit = source.Split(" ")
          .Where(x=> x.StartsWith(matchingLetter, ignoreCase, null))
          .ToArray();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < textSplit.Length && i < numberOfBlanks; i++)
        {
            madgabWords[i] = textSplit[i];
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(template, madgabWords);
        //if you are building a string to return or assign to a variable instead of printing directly to console then use:
        var madgab = string.Format(template, madgabWords);
    }
}
```

You can also try it out [online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/69Z3UU)

Comment: Thanks @DCAggie, this helped a bit but if I just use `text` on each interpolation I will only get the word "around" printed when I want different variations of words starting with 'a' that is seen in the `string textDoc`. So how would I Print the 2nd `text` starting with 'a', which is "agnostic".

Comment: Ah, then I've misunderstood what you are trying to do. Is it fair to say your goal is to: Extract all the words beginning with a given letter from a supplied string then use those words to fill the blanks in a madgab"?

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Comment: I've updated my answer, give that a shot

Comment: @StuCM any luck?

Comment: Yes, took me a while to wrap my head around it but, thank you! Much appreciated.